# How to connect a UPhysicsConstraintComponent of an AActor to an FKSphylElem (capsule body) of a ragdoll?

Tags: physics, unreal-4, unreal

I'm trying to connect an Actor's `UPhysicsConstraintComponent` to a capsule body of a ragdoll. The reason I do it this way, instead of just using sockets on the constraint, is bodies may have offsets from bones, and than connected things things would look incorrect. I'd like to connect to the physics body`FKSphylElem`  instead of the bone/socket.

The **Physics Asset** has a `TArray<UPhysicsConstraintTemplate>` called `ConstraintSetup`, which I am adding my "Actor constraint" to. It also has a `TArray<USkeletalBodySetup>` . These `USkeletalBodySetups` contain the geometries I'd like to connect to,in this case capsules as `FKSphylElems`.

I wrote some code to give my idea a test.

I am setting up bone and component names for the new constraint, but it does not connect objects, although the new `UPhysicsConstraintTemplates` and `FConstraintInstances` are added to the Phats ConstraintSetup (checked in the debugger).

```
   void UBPLibrary::ConnectConstraintToSkeletalMeshActorPhysicsAsset(
       UPhysicsConstraintComponent* Constraint,
       USkeletalMeshComponent* Mesh,
       FName BoneName) {

     if (!IsValid(Mesh) || !IsValid(Constraint))return;
 
     UPhysicsAsset* Phat = Mesh->PhysicsAssetOverride;
 
     if (!IsValid(Phat))return;
 
     UPhysicsConstraintTemplate* constraintTemplate = NewObject<UPhysicsConstraintTemplate>();
 
     FConstraintInstance * ConstraintInstance = &Constraint->ConstraintInstance;
 
     ConstraintInstance->ConstraintBone1=BoneName;
     ConstraintInstance->ConstraintBone2=FName(Constraint->GetName());
     
     constraintTemplate->DefaultInstance = *ConstraintInstance;
 
     if (!IsValid(constraintTemplate))return;
 
     Phat->ConstraintSetup.Add(constraintTemplate);
     
     //apply changes to the ragdoll
     UWorld* world = GetWorld(Constraint);
     FPhysScene* PhysScene_PhysX = world->GetPhysicsScene();
 
     Mesh->TermArticulated();
     Mesh->InitArticulated(PhysScene_PhysX);
 }
```